# Python xml : list all elements in item

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I need to list all elements in my `<product>` item, because the elements of `<product>` is variable.

XML file :

```
<catalog>
   <product>
      <element1>text 1</element1>
      <element2>text 2</element2>
      <element..>text ..</element..>
   </produc>
</catalog>
```

Python parser :
I use fast_iter because my xml file is large...

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import configs.application as configs

myfile = configs.application.tmp + '/xml_hug_file.xml'

def fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def process_element(catalog):
    print("List all element of <product>")

context = etree.iterparse(myfile, tag='catalog', events = ('end', ))
fast_iter(context, process_element)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: how can I list all elements in my product item ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*list*"? Do you mean print them on standard out? Do you mean create a `list`, the members of which are the related to your `<element...>`?

Comment: For large xml, ET already provides a function called iterparse. I guess you should also have a look at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def process_element(catalog, *args, **kwargs):
    for child in catalog.getchildren():
        print(child.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This the solution to my problem :

```
def process_element(catalog):
    for product in catalog.findall('product'):
        for element in product.findall('*'):
            print(element.tag)
            print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the XPath `'product/*[starts-with(local-name(),"element")]'`:

---

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import io

content = '''\
<catalog>
   <product>
      <element1>text 1</element1>
      <element2>text 2</element2>
      <element3>text ..</element3>
   </product>
</catalog>'''

def fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
    Author: Liza Daly
    See also http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm
    """
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        # It's safe to call clear() here because no descendants will be
        # accessed
        elem.clear()
        # Also eliminate now-empty references from the root node to elem
        for ancestor in elem.xpath('ancestor-or-self::*'):
            while ancestor.getprevious() is not None:
                del ancestor.getparent()[0]
    del context


def process_element(catalog):
    for elt in catalog.xpath('product/*[starts-with(local-name(),"element")]'):
        print(elt)

context = ET.iterparse(io.BytesIO(content), tag='catalog', events = ('end', ))
fast_iter(context, process_element)
```

yields

```
<Element element1 at 0xb7449374>
<Element element2 at 0xb744939c>
<Element element3 at 0xb74493c4>
```

---

By the way, I made an alteration to Liz Daly's fast_iter, which will delete more elements as they become unused. This should reduce memory requirements when parsing large XML files.

Here is a example which shows how the modified `fast_iter` above removes more elements than the original `fast_iter`:

```
import logging
import textwrap
import lxml.etree as ET
import io

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
level = logging.INFO
# level = logging.DEBUG  # uncomment to see more debugging information
logging.basicConfig(level=level)

def fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
    Author: Liza Daly
    See also http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm
    """
    for event, elem in context:
        logger.debug('Processing {e}'.format(e=ET.tostring(elem)))
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        # It's safe to call clear() here because no descendants will be
        # accessed
        logger.debug('Clearing {e}'.format(e=ET.tostring(elem)))
        elem.clear()
        # Also eliminate now-empty references from the root node to elem
        for ancestor in elem.xpath('ancestor-or-self::*'):
            logger.debug('Checking ancestor: {a}'.format(a=ancestor.tag))
            while ancestor.getprevious() is not None:
                logger.info('Deleting {p}'.format(
                    p=(ancestor.getparent()[0]).tag))
                del ancestor.getparent()[0]
    del context

def orig_fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):
    for event, elem in context:
        logger.debug('Processing {e}'.format(e=ET.tostring(elem)))
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        logger.debug('Clearing {e}'.format(e=ET.tostring(elem)))
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            logger.info('Deleting {p}'.format(
                p=(elem.getparent()[0]).tag))                
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def setup_ABC():
    content = textwrap.dedent('''\
      <root>
        <A1>
          <B1></B1>
          <C>1<D1></D1></C>
          <E1></E1>
        </A1>
        <A2>
          <B2></B2>
          <C>2<D></D></C>
          <E2></E2>
        </A2>
      </root>
        ''')
    return content

content = setup_ABC()
context = ET.iterparse(io.BytesIO(content), events=('end', ), tag='C')
orig_fast_iter(context, lambda elem: None)
# DEBUG:__main__:Deleting B1
# DEBUG:__main__:Deleting B2

print('-'*80)
"""
The improved fast_iter deletes A1. The original fast_iter does not.
"""
content = setup_ABC()
context = ET.iterparse(io.BytesIO(content), events=('end', ), tag='C')
fast_iter(context, lambda elem: None)
# DEBUG:__main__:Deleting B1
# DEBUG:__main__:Deleting A1
# DEBUG:__main__:Deleting B2
```

Thus you see the modified `fast_iter` manages to delete the `A1` element because it is not needed by the time the second `C` element is processed. The original `fast_iter` only deletes parents of `C` elements (i.e. `B` elements). You could imagine things like `A1` could be quite large in a large XML file, and there could be many such elements. So the modified `fast_iter` will allow reclamation of a lot of memory that the original `fast_iter` does not free.